# Zero or one argument

Tags: python, argparse

Which action I have to use, when parameter can be with zero or one argument?
I have to run code like this and will be set default value 4 
(this variant exit with error)

```
--pretty-xml
error: argument --pretty-xml: expected one argument
```

but alse I can run code like this

```
--pretty-xml = 2
```

my code looks like this

```
parameter.add_argument('--pretty-xml',  dest="pretty", action="append", default=[4])
```

What needs to be changed to work for both options parameters ?
Thanks

Comment: @abccd What needs to be changed to work for both options parameters ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to use [`nargs`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#nargs) argument with `?` and the `default` and `const` parameters:

> `'?'`. One argument will be consumed from the command line if possible,
>   and produced as a single item. If no command-line argument is present,
>   the value from default will be produced.
>   ...

---

```
parser.add_argument('--pretty-xml', dest='pretty', default=4, const=5, nargs='?', type=int)
```

This will have the value `n` if called like `--pretty-xml=n`, or `5` if called like `--pretty-xml` or 4 if `--pretty-xml` isn't present on the command line at all.

NOTE: used `type=int` to check type and convert to int type. Otherwise returns string if the argument is specified, returns int 4 if no argument is specified.

Comment: Why value is None ?
`args = parser.parse_args()
        print(args.pretty)`

Comment: @Bando, For me, it's `Namespace(pretty=4)` (no argument specified), `Namespace(pretty=2)` (`--pretty-xml=2` specified).

Comment: To get the most of out of `?` give it both a `default` and a `cost` parameter.  See the docs.

Comment: @hpaulj, Where does the `cost` come from? I can't find `cost` in the question nor in the `argparse` documentaion.

Comment: Sorry, 'const', as in constant. It's mentioned in the duplicate.